# How to efficiently use whole menus of Eclipse GWT toolkit

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I want to  learn  GWT,  so I  [downloaded the GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/download.html) and have started to look at [the tutorials of it](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html).

As far as I'm concerned, in the menus of plug-in  are  useful for  GWT users.
Do you know any tutorial web site or document which contains this  menu for adding something  or  user guide ?

I want to  use this plug efficiently so I need this.
And  any advices  in order to  learn  GWT will be beneficial for me.
Any help  and advices  will  be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Vogella's GWT Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/GWT/article.html) is a good introduction to Google Web Toolkit.

[image: "new Web application Poject" dialog]